# Subscribe to google forms program submit without ownership

Tags: node.js, networking, google-forms

With the wake of the pandemic causing schools to go to distance learning, many classes take attendance by using a simple google form sent out to students to complete for each class everyday. While this seems like a simple solution, it is a pain for students to complete and keep track of. One way that I thought I could make this easier would be to keep track of which forms I have submitted everyday.

As of now, my problem is that I need a way to subscribe to the submit of a google form (based on a link). When that google form is submitted all I need to do is find a way to convey that to a program. What I do not understand is how I would be able to do that without having ownership of the form or make a teacher recreate the form. Is there a way that I can check if a google form has been submitted?

A couple of ideas I have had would be to sniff network traffic for a post request from a google form and get that link and compare it to other links in the program to see which one was submitted, but I would think there is an easier way to do this. Any ideas or code is welcomed.

*I  understand stack overflow is for already written code so if you do not agree with this post either ignore it or point me to the correct place where this should be posted. Thank you.*

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, about `When that google form is submitted all I need to do is find a way to convey that to a program.`, in your situation, do you have the permission for editing the Google Form? If you have it, how about using the Google Apps Script and OnSubmit event trigger? When they are used, when the form is submitted, a script can be run. But if this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike hi tanaike. Thanks for your reply. I wish it was that simple and i would’ve tried that first but I do not have permission to edit any of the forms which is why this is more of a problem than it seems.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike don’t apologize - maybe it will be useful clarification for someone in the future.

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, in your case, when the form is submitted, are the values from the form put to the Spreadsheet? If it's so, do you have the permission to edit the Spreadsheet?

Comment: @Tanaike I do not have access to basically any information. I am a student. Teachers created the form to be able to log attendance for themselves so they can submit it to administration. I have to complete a form for each class and it’s a hassle to keep track of which forms i submit. My goal would be to find a way to track which forms I have submitted for the day but I unfortunately don’t have access to the form, spreadsheet or anything else

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that I couldn't help you.